# Play sound on new database entry

Tags: php, sql, ajax, jquery

So I found only 1 question that was similar to mine, and the answer didn't really help none so I am hoping asking with my own code might help me find the answer I am looking for.

I am wanting to add sound to my shoutbox when a new post is made. I believe that the piece of code that the play sound function would go would be here

```
function shouts() {
                clearTimeout(getshout);
                var xmlHttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                xmlHttp.open("GET", "shoutbox/shouts.php?i=" + Math.random());
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        if (parseInt(this.responseText) > current_shouts) {
                            getshouts();
                            current_shouts = parseInt(this.responseText);
                        }
                        getshout = setTimeout("shouts()", 1000);
                    }
                }
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
```

But I am not 100% sure, I do know that this is where it checks for new entries in the database, the corresponding php code that is called by this function is

```
<?php
    require_once("../config.php");
    echo implode(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM shout")));
?>
```

I am pretty sure that this code doesn't have to be touched in order to do this. I have done searches on Google, and checked multiple forums but I have yet to find a way that actually works, I am not asking for you guys to write the code for me, just give me a push in the right direction!

If there is anything else needed please let me know and I will edit my post.

Thanks, Casey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere on your page have

```
<audio id="myaudio" src="shout.mp3"></audio>
```

And on getting a new shout (maybe before the call to `getshouts()`) do

```
document.getElementById('myaudio').play();
```

Comment: This kind of breaks the code, i have implemented it several ways, it stops the shoutbox from loading new posts for other users. Not really sure what I did wrong :/

Comment: Thanks to victmo's post I was able to get this implemented the right way!

Answer (score 1):

I would call `audio.play()` inside `getshouts()`.

Keep in mind that the audio tag is only supported on the newest browsers. Take a look at this page for a fallback mechanism for your audio tag: http://code.coneybeare.net/getting-html5-audio-tag-and-flash-fallback-to

HTML

```
<audio id="audioplayer" preload>
    <source src="audio.mp3">
</audio>
```

Javascript

```
var audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
if (!(!!(audioTag.canPlayType) && ("no" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")) && ("" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")))) {
    AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer", {soundFile: "audio.mp3"});
}

function getshouts(){
    ... // your code

    if(success){
        audioTag.play();
    }
}
```

This code is not tested, but will give you a basic idea.

More resources:

- http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/
- http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/

Cheers!

Comment: I am so glad you posted this, I wasn't able to implement it but it gave me more of an understanding on what to do with the code that Eugen posted! Thanks so much I will give this a useful bump as soon as I have enough rep

Answer (score 0):

Continuing Eugene's post, edit your php files that adds the reply to mysql database and play the music.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what would I add into the file that actually posts the files to the database that will make it play the sound o.O

Answer (score 0):

My design was display sound file names from a single-row MySQL table and give the user the option of playing them.  The column names represent the events that precipitate the playing of the sound in the final app. Here is the PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>

    <title>Event Sounds</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />

  </head>

  <body>


    <h1><b>AZ Science Bowl</b> -- Back Room Operations</h1>
    <h2>Event Sounds Selected -- and Test Play</h2>



<?php
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=SciBwl_Operation_TestI";
$username = "********";

$password = "********";



try {

  $conn = new PDO( $dsn, $username, $password );

  $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

} catch ( PDOException $e ) {

  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

}



$sql = "SELECT * FROM SoundsSelect";



echo "<ul>";



try {

  $rows = $conn->query( $sql );

  foreach ( $rows as $row ) {

    echo "<li>For <b>Program Start:</b> " . $row["ProgStart"] . "\t<audio controls><source src=\"./sounds/" . $row["ProgStart"] . "\" type=\"audio/wav\"></audio></li>";
    echo "<li>For <b>Break & Round Start:</b> " . $row["BrkRndStart"] . "\t<audio controls><source src=\"./sounds/" . $row["BrkRndStart"] . "\" type=\"audio/wav\"></audio></li>";
    echo "<li>For <b>Toss & Bonus Start:</b> " . $row["TossBonusStart"] . "\t<audio controls><source src=\"./sounds/" . $row["TossBonusStart"] . "\" type=\"audio/wav\"></audio></li>";
    echo "<li>For <b>5 Second Warning:</b> " . $row["5SecWarn"] . "\t<audio controls><source src=\"./sounds/" . $row["5SecWarn"] . "\" type=\"audio/wav\"></audio></li>";
    echo "<li>For <b>Toss & Bonus End:</b> " . $row["TossBonusEnd"] . "\t<audio controls><source src=\"./sounds/" . $row["TossBonusEnd"] . "\" type=\"audio/wav\"></audio></li>";
    echo "<li>For <b>30 Second End of Break Warning:</b> " . $row["30SecWarn"] . "\t<audio controls><source src=\"./sounds/" . $row["30SecWarn"] . "\" type=\"audio/wav\"></audio></li>";
    echo "<li>For <b>Round End:</b> " . $row["RoundEnd"] . "\t<audio controls><source src=\"./sounds/" . $row["RoundEnd"] . "\" type=\"audio/wav\"></audio></li>";

  }

} catch ( PDOException $e ) {

  echo "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage();

}



echo "</ul>";

$conn = null;


?>

<br><br>
    </body>

</html>
```